# get time in different inputs with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, date

Im trying to reuse a simple function that prints the time when a button is clicked.
I have a button for each input. When I want to update the time, I click the button.

Well, I dont know how to pass from HTML/PHP to Javascript a variable, which includes the ID of the input, avoidint to create the same Javascript code to each input

If I write in the document.getElementById() line the name of the input between quotes, it works, but i want to use a variable.

Sorry for my english!

```
    <html>
      <head>
       <script type="text/javascript">
    function TellMeTime(input_selected)
    {var fecha = new Date();
        document.getElementById(input_selected).value = fecha.getFullYear() +'-' + fecha.getMonth() +'-'+ fecha.getDay() + ' ' + fecha.getHours() +':'+ fecha.getMinutes() +':'+ fecha.getSeconds();}
       </script>
      </head>
      <body>
       <form>
        <input type="button" onclick="TellMeTime(hello)" value="<- Hello">
        <input type="text" size="80" id="hello" name="hello" value="nothing yet"> 
        <br><hr>

            <input type="button" onclick="TellMeTime(bye)" value="<- Bye">
        <input type="text" size="80" id="bye" name="bye" value="nothing yet"> 
       </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a string as argument to the function in Javascript. Strings are represented with values inside single `'` or double quotes `"`

in your HTML your are passing the id string value  as your argument. you can use like this

```
onclick="TellMeTime('hello')" 
onclick="TellMeTime('bye')"
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you, it works!  I recognize I'm newbie in this world

Answer (score 0):

To pass a variable from PHP to JavaScript you just need to do something like this:

```
<?php

<script>
    // it's a string, so we use quotes
    var foo = '<?php echo $myVariable; ?>'
</script>
```